# How to start a httpd inside a docker busybox in a single line

Tags: docker, apache

Why the commands to start an httpd inside a busybox container do not work?

```
docker run -d --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --name webserver busybox /bin/httpd -p 8080
```

or

```
docker run -d --rm -p 8080:8080 --name webserver busybox sh -c '/bin/httpd -p 8080'
```

The container just exits.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

---

The other ways below work. Wonder why the above does not work.

```
$ docker run -d --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --name webserver busybox
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS        PORTS                                       NAMES
ad92d0d4e9ac   busybox   "sh"      2 seconds ago   Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   webserver

$ docker exec -it webserver /bin/sh
/ # httpd -p 8080
/ # exit

$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

```
$ docker run -d --rm --name my-apache-container -p 80:80 busybox sh -c 'echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nWelcome to Apache!" | nc -l -p 80'

$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Welcome to Apache!
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: For the first way you listed above, I have an idea and could run successfully on my ubuntu： `docker run -d --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --name l01-web busybox sh -c 'httpd -p 8080 && /bin/sh'`, however, has not found the specific reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `httpd` in the foreground (`-f`) to keep the shell process, and therefore the container, alive:

```
$ docker run -d --rm -it -p 8080:8080 --name webserver busybox /bin/httpd -f -p 8080
```